# HTML select options from a python list

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm writing a python cgi script to setup a Hadoop cluster. 
I want to create an HTML select dropdown where the options are taken from a python list. Is this possible?? 
I've looked around a lot. Couldn't find any proper answer to this.

This is what i've found so far on another thread...

```
def makeSelect(name,values):
    SEL = '<select name="{0}">\n{1}</select>\n'
    OPT = '<option value="{0}">{0}</option>\n'
    return SEL.format(name, ''.join(OPT.format(v) for v in values))
```

I really need some help. Please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a list of "option"s and pass them over to your javascript to make the list

```
values = {"A": "One", "B": "Two", "C": "Three"}
options = []

for value in sorted(values.keys()):
    options.append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + values[value] + "</option>")
```

Then inject "options" into your html. Say, in your "template.html" there is a line:

```
var options = $python_list;
```

Then at the end of your python script:

```
####open the html template file, read it into 'content'
html_file = "template.html"
f = open(html_file, 'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()

####replace the place holder with your python-generated list
content = content.replace("$python_list", json.dumps(options))

####write content into the final html
output_html_file = "index.html"
f = open(output_html_file, 'w')
f.write(temp_content)
f.close()
```

In your "index.html", you should have one line after "var options = ..." that takes the list and generate the dropdown.

```
$('#my_dropdown').append(options.join("")).selectmenu();
```

Alternatively, I suggest that you use your python to generate a json file (with json.dumps()), a file called "config.json" maybe. And your html javascript file should read this json file to render the final page. So in your json file, there should be something like:

{ ... "options": ["One", "Two", "Three"] ...}

And in your html `<script>` section, you could read the option values

```
d3.json("config.json", function(data)) {
 var options = [];
 for (var i= 0; i < data.options.length; i++)
    {
      options.push("<option value='" + data.options[i] + "'>" + data.options[i] + "</option>");

    }
 $('#my_dropdown').append(options.join("")).selectmenu();
}
```

Comment: Wow. Ok. It's gonna take me a while to understand all of this. 
I have no idea how json works so I don't think that's a viable option for me. But thank you so much.

Comment: Umm, why is values taken as a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. Because so far, i've only got a single .cgi script which has all my html code as well as the required python code. So I don't understand why you're opening a file and then taking the output into another one. Sorry. I'm new at python.

Comment: What kind of interaction do you have with your cgi code? The cgi script should have its html somewhere, either hardcoded in itself or it takes a template somewhere and modifies it and returns it. Either way, you need to access that html part and adapt it so that your python code can hand over the options.

Comment: The cgi code as well as the html are all in a single file. I'm using print """ html """ to print the html sections.

Comment: Then in the cgi file, you need to find the html section and modify it so that it can accept the results from your python script.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly the easiest way to do this. Simply update your options using a FOR loop using Python in HTML...eg:

Here is a Select List that I am populating with an array called myOptions that I passed to the form. I also added an If statement that checks to see if one of the values in the list is = to myValue and pre-selected that value. That is totally optional.

```
 <select>
        {% for opt in myOptions %}
            <option value={{ opt }} 
               {% if myValue==opt %} 
                   selected="true"
               {% endif %}>{{ opt }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier way to do this.

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
lister = ['a','b','c']

html_list = ''
for value in lister:
   html_list += '<option value={0}>{0}</option>'.format(value)

html = """Content-type: text/html\n

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select>
   {}
</select>
</body>
</html>
""".format(html_list)
print(html)
```

More details here: http://python-forum.io/Thread-string-format-and-string-expressions